# Android Studio does not find debuggable processes on Samsung phones

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, samsung-galaxy, samsung-knox

I am having an issue with some new testing devices I have started using: Samsung Galaxy S7 (OS 7.0) and S9 (OS 10.0). While I can build and deploy debug apks to the devices over USB (using "Run" button), and see the devices listed in the devices dropdown and the logcat dropdown, I do not see the debuggable process listed in the attach menu, or in the logcat. When I attempt to "Debug" (Run + Attach), the device shows a prompt indefinitely waiting for the debugger to attach.

I do see that Samsung Knox is part of both of these phones (v2.7.1 and v3.4.1 respectively) - I fully understand if there are some gotchas with knox and debugging since that may be one of the security areas it attempts to protect. Haven't been able to find any documentation to prove that or understand how to disable knox enough to get the devices debugging.

I am using Android Studio 4.0.1 on Max OS 10.15.6. I have not had any issues debugging Moto and Pixel devices.

Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have this a lot recently.

Usually, the next command fixes it for me:

```
adb kill-server
```

Comment: Yup, thank you. Weird that it gets into a state where it works for some and not others.

Comment: I'm on canary version, so I didn't complain about it. But since you have it on the stable version, I would report it to Google.